# Inject an empty string via Structuremap xml config

Tags: xml, structuremap, config

When I use the following in a structuremap xml config file, it is like I didn't specify the captureFileName parameter at all.

How can I inject an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the value as captureFileName="STRING.EMPTY" in the XML. Its an old hack in StructureMap to get around the fact that XML treats an empty attribute as non-existent.